# Redireccionar de example.com/1111.php a example.com/2222.php en JavaScipt

Tags: javascript, redirección

Estoy intentando poner en el header de mi web este código que intenta redireccionar una pagina de la web a otra pagina de la misma web, pero no consigo que funcione, el código en cuestión es este;

```
<script>
if (window.location.href = "/1111.php") {
    window.location.replace("/2222.php");
}
</script>
```

Se queda en un bucle de redirecciones

Gracias y saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un par de cosas, comenzando con que en JS el operador lógico de igual es `==` o `===` de otra manera estas asignando un valor (por esto es el bucle). Segundo, el método `replace`, no te dejara utilizar el botón back del historial en su lugar podrías simplemente usar `assign`, igualmente solo con obtener el pathname y asignar relativamente el nuevo path ya esta.

**Algo mas correcto seria lo siguiente**:

```javascript
const string = '/1111.php'
if (window.location.pathname === string || window.location.pathname.includes(string))
   window.location.href = '/2222.php'
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda, un saludo.

Comment: Gracias por contestar el código funciona perfecto pero tengo un problema ya que utilizo una carga de los artículos con `JQuery` desde el enlace al hacer click para acceder a `/1111.php` no redirecciona a `/2222.php` muestra aun `/1111.php` hasta que cargo la página de nuevo, entonces si que redirecciona a `/2222.php`. ¿como se puede añadir a esta función que actualice  `/2222.php` después de acceder a `/2222.php`?

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu comentario, todo depende, si el codigo redirecciona es porque funciona, probablemente sea un problema de carga de scripts